# PHP 5.3: how to add PDFlib?

Tags: php, pdflib

I recently upgraded my Linux server from Apache 2.1 to 2.4 and PHP 5.2 to 5.3. Previously I was using pdf.so from PDFlib fine, but when I tried to install it, as downloaded from here,

http://www.pdflib.com/download/free-software/pdflib-lite-7/

PHP failed to load the module as it was compiled in for PHP 5.3. This install was done using the newest version of PDFlib that I could find, 9.0.2.

Anyone know whether this is possible? I've already got things coded in PHP for PDFlib and prefer not to use another library unless the commands are the same.

UPDATE

Has anyone successfully used PDF Lite with PHP 5.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must **compile** it. Currently no build is available for `PHP 5.3`.

On the Download-Site, **READ** the info:

`PDFlib Lite source code must be compiled to generate a usable library. PDFlib GmbH does not offer precompiled (binary) versions of PDFlib Lite.`

If you have compile errors, **check out** the error logs - What say it? Yep, i think you need additional sources for compiling (mostly).

Comment: Thanks... was `pdf.so` replaced by something else (`pdflib.so` maybe?). Does compiling PDFlib Lite source code create a `pdf.so` or `pdflib.so` file?

Comment: You can see it, in the logs! Otherwise, check your compiling arguments - Here you must specific if the compiled binary is an shared library, otherwise it's in the PHP-Extension dir.